# Pairwise plot of 2D heatmap in Plotly Express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, heatmap, plotly-python

I have a Pandas dataframe like the following:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [1,2,1,1,2,1],
                       'rating': [2,1,1,3,4,5],
                       'speed': [1,5,5,3,2,4],
                       'value':[4,4,3,2,2,1],
                       'appearance':[1,2,3,3,1,1],
                       'will_buy': [2,2,1,5,2,3]})
```

This is for a consumer study where columns are all categorical and only takes on a limited set of fixed values. For instance, in 'gender', 1 might denote 'male', and 2 might denote 'female'. In 'value', 1 might mean 'poor', and 5 might mean 'excellent'.

It would be useful to see a pairwise plot of the data to notice any trend.

I tried to use Plotly Express to create a pair plot, this is for a Streamlit dashboard:

```
pairplot_fig = px.scatter_matrix(df, dimensions = df.columns)
st.plotly_chart(pairplot_fig)
```

[image]

As you can see, due to the categorical nature of the data, the pair plot does not tell a lot of information. For instance, there might be many observations at a certain location, but it only shows up as one dot. Moreover, the column names on the left edge are cluttered due to lack of spacing.

I then tried to create a 2D heatmap that will show the number of observations at each location. This will help uncover insights like "many people who selected 5 for value also tend to select 5 for speed."

```
    heatmap_fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x= 'gender', y='rating', 
                              marginal_x="histogram", marginal_y="histogram")
    st.plotly_chart(heatmap_fig, theme = None)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I can only figure out how to generate the heatmap of 1 column VS 1 column. It would be ideal to generate a heatmap that is many columns to many columns, just like the pair plot.

I hope to do this in Plotly Express as it's interactive. But if that's not possible, a solution in other plotting packages like Seaborn would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You problably need to use subplots and configure it as you wish:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'rating': [2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5],
                   'speed': [1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4],
                   'value': [4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1],
                   'appearance': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
                   'will_buy': [2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3]})

fig = make_subplots(1, 2, horizontal_spacing=0.15)
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=df[["gender", "rating"]]), 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=df[["gender", "rating"]]), 1, 2)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this in plotly express (which has really easy/nice faceting capabilities), you need to make the dataframe 'long'. I had to melt the data twice to get all the combinations in a long format. I would be interested if there was an alternative way than this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'rating': [2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5],
                   'speed': [1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4],
                   'value': [4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1],
                   'appearance': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
                   'will_buy': [2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3]})

selectedChannelNames = ["gender", "rating", "speed", "value", "appearance", "will_buy"]
var_name = "variable-1"  
melt_df = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=[col for col in df.columns if col not in selectedChannelNames],
    value_vars=selectedChannelNames,
    value_name="y-value",
    var_name=var_name,
)

df_concat = pd.DataFrame(
    np.tile(df[selectedChannelNames].values, (len(selectedChannelNames), 1)),
    columns=selectedChannelNames,
)

plot_df = pd.concat([melt_df, df_concat], axis=1)

var_name2 = "variable-2" 
melt_df2 = pd.melt(
    plot_df,
    id_vars=[col for col in plot_df.columns if col not in selectedChannelNames],
    value_vars=selectedChannelNames,
    value_name="x-value",
    var_name=var_name2,
)

fig = px.density_heatmap(melt_df2,
    x = 'x-value',
    y = 'y-value',
    facet_row = var_name,
    facet_col = var_name2,
    title = 'density_heatmap_gender_gender',
    color_continuous_scale = [[0, 'white'], [0.01, '#440154'], [0.1111111111111111, '#482878'], [0.2222222222222222, '#3e4989'], [0.3333333333333333, '#31688e'], [0.4444444444444444, '#26828e'], [0.5555555555555556, '#1f9e89'], [0.6666666666666666, '#35b779'], [0.7777777777777778, '#6ece58'], [0.8888888888888888, '#b5de2b'], [1.0, '#fde725']],
    height = 1000,
    width = 1100,
                    )
fig.update_layout(template='simple_white')
fig.show()
```

[image]